# scheduler дважды выполняет одну задачу в проекте Django

Tags: django

Подскажите почему фоновая задача в приложении Django выполняется дважды каждые 10 сек? Что здесь не так?

*project/main/apps.py*

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MainConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'main'

    def ready(self):
        from . import updater
        updater.start()
```

*project/main/updater.py*

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from .something_update import update_something


def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(update_something, 'interval', seconds=10)
    scheduler.start()
```

*project/main/something_update.py*

```
def update_something():
    print("this function runs every 10 seconds")
```

Comment: А как вы запускаете Django?

Comment: @andreymal командой python manage.py runserver
При этом debug=False

Comment: Впрочем, независимо от этого запускать scheduler так — плохая идея, потому что на продакшене обязательно должны запускаться несколько экземпляров Django (иначе банально будет тормозить), тогда и scheduler станет выполняться сильно чаще чем дважды. Вынесите запуск в отдельный management command и запускайте это всё отдельным процессом

Comment: А в случае с runserver (который запускать на продакшене, напомню, нельзя) это связано с тем, что запускается два процесса: один мониторит изменения и перезапускает сервер, а второй собственно является сервером. Опция `--noreload` исправит двойной запуск, но это всё равно неправильное решение, потому что правильно сделать management command

Comment: @andreymal но как объяснить, что на development эта проблема остается даже при debug=False?

Comment: debug=False и reload никак друг с другом не связаны